# Create production release in new Google play store console

Tags: android

Am trying to update my android APK on new google play store  console, but it's throwing error while uploading to play store. please any help?

Comment: Share error you have received.

Comment: Couldn't upload. Try again.

Answer (score 0):

For me google plays says your release is not signed for both format APK and AAB.
I've an old Key store file.
what I found, sign AAB file manually. use this bat file:

```
    cls
    rem 1- Create new folder, get path of file JarSigner, normally in Java folder
    rem 2- get Alies -->  myAlias, and password --> myPassword
    rem 3- get StoreFile in the same dir --> myKeystoreFileName
    rem 4- Get copy of unsigned ytour application aab file named --> app-release.aab 

    C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\JarSigner -verbose -sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA-256 -storepass myPassword -keystore myKeystoreFileName app-release.aab myAlias
```